# Find the critical points of $[x^1,x^2,x^3] \to \frac{3(x^1)^2}{(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2+(x^3)^2}$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}P^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$[x^1,x^2,x^3] \to \frac{3(x^1)^2}{(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2+(x^3)^2}$$.

1. Find all the critical points of $f$.  Hint: you need to check in all three of our standard coordinate charts $\{(Ui,\phi_i)\}_{i=1,2,3}$.

- $(U_1,\phi_1)$:

$Id \circ f \circ (\phi_1)^{-1} (x^1,x^2)=f (1,x^1,x^2)= \frac{3}{1+(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2}$

We have
$$[f_*]=
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{-6x^1}{(1+(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2)^2} & \frac{-6x^2}{(1+(x^2)^2+(x^2)^2)^2} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

This equals to $0$ when $x^1=x^2=0$. So the critical points take the form $(0,0,a)$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}$

- $(U_2,\phi_2)$:

$Id \circ f \circ (\phi_2)^{-1} (x^1,x^2)=f(x^1,1,x^2)=\frac{3(x^1)^2}{1+(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2}$

We have
$$[f_*]=
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{6x^1(1+(x^2)^2)}{(1+(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2)^2} & \frac{-6(x^1)^2x^2}{(1+(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2)^2} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

This equals to $0$ when $x^1=0$. So the critical points take the form $(0,b,c)$ where $b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

- For $(U_3,\phi_3)$, I got the same as the chart $(U_2,\phi_2)$.

As a result, the critical points $\{(0,0,a),(0,b,c)\}$.

Is it correct?

2. Find the point at which f takes its maximum value.

I know that I should substitute the critical points into $f$. But I got $0$ in all of them:

$f(0,0,a)=0$

$f(0,b,c)=0$

My teacher told me that only one of them would be $0$, so I think there is something wrong in the step $1$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes, in the step 1, the critical points over the chart $(U_1,\phi_1)$ are such the form $(a,0,0)$, do you wrote $(0,0,a)$. You missed the fact that $x^1$ is not the first entry in the function. The maximum, after correct would be $1$.

Comment: @DiegoMath Oh you’re right! Thank you so much.